# Powershell to merge directories

Tags: powershell, merge, directory

I am trying to use powershell to merge directories. I am trying to get rid of the parent directories as they are not needed (recovered files from failing drive). So example current structure is JunkFolder1>RecoveredDirectory>Year>ClientDirectory

There are multiple junk folders and they may or may not have the same RecoveredDirectory, Year, ClientDirectory.

I want to run a script that will eliminate all the junk folders and merge the rest, without deleting any files at the ClientDirectory level.

I am super new to PS, but figured it would be the best route. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$sourcePath,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$destinationPath
)


$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -Filter "*.*"

foreach($file in $files){
    $sourcePathFile = $file.FullName
    $destinationPathFile = $file.FullName.Replace($sourcePath,  $destinationPath)

    $exists = Test-Path $destinationPathFile

    If (!$exists){
        $dir = Split-Path -parent $destinationPathFile
        if (!(Test-Path($dir))) { New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $dir }
        Copy-Item -Path $sourcePathFile -Destination $destinationPathFile -Recurse -Force
    }
    else{
        $isFile = Test-Path -Path $destinationPathFile -PathType Leaf

        if($isFile){
            $different = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $sourcePathFile) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $destinationPathFile)
            if(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $sourcePathFile) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $destinationPathFile)){
            $dir = Split-Path -parent $destinationPathFile
            if (!(Test-Path($dir))) { New-Item -Type directory -Path $dir }

                Copy-Item -Path $sourcePathFile -Destination $destinationPathFile -Recurse -Force
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call this by: `ScriptName.ps1 "SourceDir" "DestinationDir"`

Attribution: https://dejanstojanovic.net/powershell/2018/february/merge-folders-with-windows-powershell-script/

Comment: This is getting me in the right direction...thank you...when trying to run it though I am getting an error saying that Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null.  

The script runs, but just copies the existing structure, it is not merging anything.